# get tagname in xml using php

Tags: php, xml, dom, getelementsbytagname

Here is my xml:

```
<news_item>    
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <content>COTENT.</content>
    <date>DATE</date>
<news_item>
```

I want to get the names of the tags inside of news_item.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($file_name);
$results = $dom->getElementsByTagName('news_item');
```

**WITHOUT USING other php libraries like simpleXML**, can I get the name of all the tag names (not values) of the children tags?

Example solution

```
title, content, date
```

I don't know the name of the tags inside of news_item, only the container tag name 'news_item'

Thanks guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How get first level of dom elements by Domdocument PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882433/how-get-first-level-of-dom-elements-by-domdocument-php)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($results as $node)
{
    if($node->childNodes->length)
    {
        foreach($node->childNodes as $child)
        {
            echo $child->nodeName,', ';
        }
    }
}
```

Should work. Using something similar currently, though for html not xml.

Answer (score 2):

```
$nodelist = $results->getElementsByTagName('*');
for( $i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++)
    echo $nodelist->item($i)->nodeName;
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this one would have worked, I just implemented the first answer before yours, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Previous incorrect answer redacted]

For what it's worth though, there's no cost to using simplexml_import_dom() to make a SimpleXMLElement out of a DOMElement. Both are just object interfaces into an underlying libxml2 data structure. You can even make a change to the DOMElement and see it reflected in the SimpleXMLElement or vice versa. So it doesn't have to be an either/or choice.

Comment: Huh, yeah it is. I muffed that up pretty well.